# Lion and wildebeest population modelling question issue

Tags: exponential-function, quadratics, exponentiation, mathematical-modeling

I am a student completing A levels and recently received the following question in an official mock exam for the Edexcel A-level in Mathematics. Having discussed the question extensively with my peers and teachers but to no avail, I would appreciate if if you could shed some light on where I went wrong.

**The question:**

> An ecologist is investigating the number of lions and wildebeest in a national park.
>
> The number of lions, measured in hundreds, $L$, is modelled by the equation $L = 1 + 2e^{0.03t}$ where $t$ is the number of years from the start of the investigation.
>
> The number of wildebeest, measured in thousands, $W$ is modelled by the equation $W = 10 + 4e^{-0.03t}$ where $t$ is the number of years from the start of the investigation.
>
> When $t = T$, according to the models, there are 10 times as many lions as wildebeest. Find the value of $T$ to one decimal place.

**My solution:**

Since $L$ is measured in the hundreds, I defined a new variable $L'$ as the *actual* number of lions. Since $L$ is measured in the hundreds, I found that $L' = 100L$. Similarly for wildebeest, I defined $W'$ as the *actual* number of wildebeest. Since $W$ is measured in the thousands, I found that $W' = 1000W$.

If when $t = T$ the number of lions is 10 times the number of wildebeest, that means $L' = 10W'$. Substituting the values for $L'$ and $W'$, this means $100L = 10000W$ and so $L = 100W$.

Solving the equations when this condition is true gave the following:

$1 + 2e^{0.03T} = 100(10 + 4e^{-0.03T}) \Rightarrow 2e^{0.06T} - 999e^{0.03T} - 400 = 0$

$\require{cancel} e^{0.03T} \approx 499.9, \cancel{-0.4} \Rightarrow 0.03T \approx 6.21 \Rightarrow T \approx 207.1$ years

**Mark scheme solution (word for word):**

Set $L = W$

$1 + 2e^{0.03T} = 10 + 4e^{-0.03T} \Rightarrow 2(e^{0.03T})^2 - 9 - 4e^{0.03T} = 0$

$e^{0.03T} \approx 4.907, \cancel{-0.4075} \Rightarrow 0.03T \approx ln(4.907) \Rightarrow T \approx 53.0$ years

**Final:**

When I substituted $t = 207.1$ years into the expressions for $L$ and $W$, I got the values 100080 and 10.008 respectively which seem to satisfy the conditions considering $L$ is in hundreds and $W$ is in the thousands.

Thank you for taking a look at this, I'd appreciate any advice you may have about this. As you can imagine, this was an exam question and so I really would like to clarify this.

Comment: It is probably an error setting out the question.  Their solution found $t$ when $L=W$, i.e. when there were $10$ times as many wildebeest as lions, rather than when there were  $10$ times as many lions as wildebeest.

Comment: That's what I thought as well. I wondered if there could be some vagueness in the interpretation of "there are 10 times as many lions as wildebeest" to mean that there are 10x more wildebeest than lions but having consulted an English teacher, they said that couldn't be the case. Just wondering why they decided to go that way in this official mark scheme.